# What happens when you put a .method after an object?

Tags: java

i am trying to understand why this won't run.  I am thinking that I may need to import a package.  I would also like to know what happens in the class LocalVariables on the the line myObject.f();

I think that I have just instantiated myObject on the previous line but am I calling the f method with myObject.f();   ?????  I don't understand what is supposed to happen on that line.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
class MyObject{
 static short s = 400; //static variable
 int i = 200;  //instance variable

 void f() {
     System.out.println("s = " + s);
     System.out.println("i = " + i);
     short s = 300;  //local variable
     int i = 100;  //local variable
     double d = 1E100;  //local variable
     System.out.println("s = "+s);
     System.out.println("i = " +i);
     System.out.println("d = " + d);
          }
     }


class LocalVariables{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
        myObject.f();
    }
}
```

Comment: I mean no disrespect, but this is an *extremely* elementary question.  I suggest you pick up a book and do some reading on Java so you understand what a method invocation is.

Comment: thanks Kirk, this is from Osborn "Teach yourself Java", and I am trying to understand the book.  The page is 153.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
change void f() to public void f() { //Code... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are calling the `f()` method. Thus flow of control will jump to the top of the `f()` function and execute those statements one by one.

Once it is done, it will go back to the `main` method, resuming where it had left off. This doesn't mean anything here, since `myObject.f()` is the last line, but if you had more code then that would be executed once the `f()` method returns.

Comment: @doug: Click the check-mark (or tick, if you're British and that's what you call it) under the number of votes for the answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Well executing this should have printed a few lines

```
s = 400
i = 200
s = 300
i = 100
d = <something>
```

Did anything of this sort appear in your output?